# call typedef in objective C "id" from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to changing code from Objective-c to Swift.

**connection.h:**

```
typedef BOOL (*data_function)(id contextObject, NSArray* data, Boolean done, int error);

-(int)getData:(NSString)dataType withCallback:(data_function)processFunc withContext:(id)context;
```

Below is Objective-c program.
**ViewController.m**

```
-(void) callFun
{

int status = [objInstance getData:”1” withCallback:updateData withContext:self];

}

static BOOL updateData(id contextObject, NSArray* data, Boolean done, int error)
{

}
```

The above things, I tried to convert in Swift as below:

***ViewController.swift:***

```
fun callFun()
{
var status = objInst.getData(“1”, withCallback: updateData, withContext: self)
}


func updateData(contextObject:id, data:NSArray, done:CBool, error:Int) -> CBool {

}
```

I got the below error.

```
—
error: use of undeclared type 'id'; did you mean to use 'AnyObject'?
    func updateData(contextObject:id, data:NSArray, done:CBool, error:Int) -> CBool {
                                       ^~
                                       AnyObject
/xxx/ViewController.swift:149:78: error: 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'updateData'
        var status = objInst.getData(“1”, withCallback: updateData, withContext: self)

—
```

***Updated:***

I did changed the “id” to "AnyObject", but shows different error.

```
—
error: '(AnyObject, data: NSArray, done: Bool, error: Int) -> Bool' is not convertible to 'data_function’
        var status = objInst.readData(“1”, withCallback: updateData, withContext: self)
—
```

Any ideas why I got error or I missed something else ?

Thanks !

Comment: Isn't the answer right there in the message? `id` doesn't exist in Swift, did you mean to use `AnyObject`?

Comment: Where's your swift definition of data_function?

Comment: @jrturton: func updateData()...which i specified in swift part.. <connection.h> is external API. i access up to header file...

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is already telling you what the problem is. The `id` type in objective C is mapped as `AnyObject` in swift, which represent any reference type. So your function should look like:

```
func updateData(contextObject: AnyObject, data:NSArray, done:CBool, error:Int) -> CBool
```

Note: if `contextObject` can be `nil`, then you should use an optional:

```
func updateData(contextObject: AnyObject?, data:NSArray, done:CBool, error:Int) -> CBool
```

Also, is there any reason why you are using `CBool`? If not, then it's probably better to use `Bool`. `CBool` is just a typealias for `Bool`, but it makes the code less readable in my opinion.

Suggested reading: [id Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_30)

Comment: Thanks, m8! Starting up with Swift today so everything is kind of strange (:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Swift keyword that is equivalent to `id` is `AnyObject`, as the error message and [the Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_516) helpfully notes.